# How can I use ReSharper to list unused methods in a solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

In a legacy ASP.NET project I have inherited, there are an abundance of methods defined  which are used absolutely nowhere.

I'm familiar with the "Find usages" functionality, but would like to be able to generate a list of methods which are not called anywhere in the app.  Does such functionality exist?

Comment: See if this helps: [Resharper- Find all unused classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646174/resharper-find-all-unused-classes). Or this: [Find unused code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code). Or this: [Find Unused public functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846821/find-unused-public-functions).

Comment: An interesting problem. Is Resharper able to detect methods that are used as event handlers but only mentioned in the markup?

Comment: Turn on solution wide analysis - unused methods will turn grey

Comment: @publicgk Thanks for those!  It appears ReSharper used to call them "Unused symbols" and has since renamed them as per Gauthier's answer.

Comment: @AnnL.  That is a good question!  FxCop might be able to do this?

Comment: @levelnis  This I have been using, what I was asking was if ReSharper could provide me with a list of these, as I have hundreds.

Comment: this question is closed because it's a duplicate of another __closed__ question. Wow.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You can select ReSharper => Inspect => Codes Issues in solution ;
And there, you can group by "Issue Type" and you should see all issues that match with "Type or type member is never used" (unused method goes there)

(And if you click right on it, you can select : "Show only "type or type member is never used" issues" .. and there you go ;)

[image: ReSharper[1]]

Comment: Thanks a TON!  I'd give you a vote but do not have the reputation.

Comment: To add to this answer, if you don't see any results, go to: ReSharper => Options => Code Inspection => Settings => Check off "Analyze errors in whole solution"

Comment: @Tarka +1 Now seems to be: ReSharper => Options => Code Inspection => Settings => and **check** "_Enable solution-wide analysis_".

Comment: You need to turn on solution-wide analysis mentioned by @AnthonyWalsh to get the non-private to be found - otherwise it shows the "n/a" shown in the screenshot

Comment: "And if you click right on it" - What is "it"? If I do ReSharper => Inspect => Code Issues, it looks NOTHING like the screenshot. I have no checkboxes. There are no context menus or anything that I can see to right-click on.

Comment: @CliveGalway I think what was meant by "And if you click right on it" is that you can select the items you wish to filter. The screenshot above is only visible when you click on the '**Filter Issues...**' button in the '**Inspection Results**' panel. Please have a look at [this excellent post](https://chrisseroka.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/find-unused-private-and-public-methods-with-resharper) that includes some helpful screenshots. BTW: Sorry, I would have replied to this sooner if I had seen it! I hope you got sorted.

Comment: @AnthonyWalsh I honestly don't remember :) Thanks for the clarification and that link though, very handy